# unable to delete a strangely behaving directory

Tags: command-line, delete

I am unable to delete a directory inside my pen drive. The directory is actually empty. When I right click on it and look for its properties, I can just see `Contents: nothing`. But when I try to delete it from terminal, it says `rm: cannot remove 'x': Directory not empty`. *x is the name of the directory which I wanna delete*. I have tried all the following. But nothing has helped me till now.

- I got a window which read `Cannot delete directory` when i used <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>. The window also had an error details option. When I clicked on it, it read `Directory not empty`
- As I said earlier, I got a message `rm: cannot remove 'x': Directory not empty` when I tried deleting it from terminal using the `rm -rf x` command. And I trying it from my pen drive. So, I hope the path x isn't any issue here
- I gave it a shot with `rm -ir x`. Firstly it showed `rm: descend into directory 'x'?`. I entered *y* and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. It showed `rm: remove directory 'x'?`. I confirmed again. It displayed `Input/output error`
- I was wanting to get rid of it somehow. So, eventhough I knew that both `rm -r x` and `rn - R x` are the same, I made a mad try with `rm -R x`. It showed the same `rm: cannot remove 'x': Directory not empty`
- I tried using `rmdir x` as I was sure that it had no contents inside it. Yet, it was a failure. It showed `rmdir: failed to remove 'x': Directory not empty`

Help me delete that strangely behaving directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds as if the pen drive is starting to fail.

Comment: `ls -a x` may well show a hidden file, which the `rm -rf x` command should remove. Try `sudo rm -rf x`?

Comment: @MarkWilliams: I have tried `ls -a x`. Even it displayed nothing.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Really a bad news for me :(

Comment: It happens with flash drives, back up your data and you can try fsck

Comment: Is there by chance a tab/little switch on the flash drive that is locking it?

Comment: @jbrock: Nothing like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encounter such a problem, try like this.

- right click your directory which disturbs you
- choose **Move to trash** so that it is trashed
- open your Trash
- click **Empty**.

Your differently behaving directory will be deleted successfully. This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a pen drive, the file system is most probably FAT or NTFS.

Therefore: Go to a Windows machine and insert the pen drive and execute the following command:

```
CHKDSK /F X:
```

where X is the actual drive letter on that machine.

Then right-click the directory under Windows and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> it.
If that doesn't work either, follow [these official Microsoft instructions to take ownership](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx) and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> it.

If you don't have a Windows machine available, leave a comment below and I'll give you the Ubuntu commands (will only work for FAT, not NTFS)